# Загрузка .DLL в C# по пользовательскому пути.

Tags: dll, c#

Использую некую dll написанную ну C# в своем приложении на C#. Нужно сделать возможность, что бы она не лежала в папке с программой, а пользователь сам выбирал ее место расположение. Как это организовать.

Comment: Указать полный абсолютный путь? И прочитать секцию Remarks в статье про LoadLibrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например у вас есть какой-то глобальный интерфейс

```
   interface IMyInterface
    {
        string GetText();
    }
```

От которого наследуются классы в вашей dll

В вашей программе следует подключить System.Reflection;
И можно работать с библиотекой

```
    string iMyInterfaceName = typeof(IMyInterface).ToString();
    Type[] defaultConstructorParametersTypes = new Type[0];
    object[] defaultConstructorParameters = new object[0];
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(<pathToDll>);
    List<IMyInterface> list = new List<IMyInterface>();
    foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (type.GetInterface(iMyInterfaceName) != null)
        {
            ConstructorInfo defaultConstructor = type.GetConstructor(defaultConstructorParametersTypes);
            object instance = defaultConstructor.Invoke(defaultConstructorParameters);
            list.Add(instance as IMyInterface);
        }
    }

    foreach (IMyInterface item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.GetText());
    }
```

тут мы пробегаемся по типам описанным в dll, и если класс реализует интерфейс, создаем нужный instance и добавляем в список
Для каждого элемента мы можем выполнять метод GetText() 
Вообще скорее всего подразумевается обычно один нужный класс в dll

Или если не реализуются интерфейсы:
Для определения всех методов у Type есть метод GetMethods(), возвращает MethodInfo[]
Для выбора метода Type.GetMethod(methodName) (есть перегрузки)
Дальше ищите в сторону рефлексии (все по аналогии)